# Powershell script to Insert multiple lines based on a pattern match

Tags: powershell

I have an appsettings.json file I'm trying to add the following lines to based on a pattern match. I'm looking for the string:"MockDocumentTypes":
and after that I want to insert the lines in the powershell script. When I run the script, the only change is that my pattern match is replaces with a space. Here is the powershell script:

```
$File = "C:\tmp\appsettings.json"
$NewContent = Get-Content -Path $File |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_
        if ($_ -match ('^' + '`"MockDocumentTypes`":'))
        {
            '"From"`: `['
             "LoanStatement",
             "BillingStatement"
        }
    }
$NewContent | Out-File -FilePath $File -Encoding Default -Force
```

Here's a section of the file.

```
"DocumentConfiguration": {
    "BasePath": "https://url",
    "Timeout": "1000000"
    "MockDocumentTypes": {
  },
```

Comment: Don't use regex for XML - parse it as an actual XML document, modify it, and then save back to disk once done. Can you share sample XML? Or at least a tag/element that has the `MockDocumentTypes` string in it?

Comment: Can you share more of a segment? That sure doesn't look like XML, instead it looks like a JSON file.

Comment: Quite right HAL9256. Well spotted it is a json file. Sorry for the confusion. I made the appropriate updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell's `CovertFrom-Json` cmdlet to parse a json-based settings file - at which point you can modify the resulting object, and then turn it back into JSON with `ConvertTo-Json`:

```
# In real life you'd just read the file with `Get-Content`
$original = @'
{
  "DocumentConfiguration": {
    "BasePath": "https://url",
    "Timeout": "1000000",
    "MockDocumentTypes": {
    }
  }    
}
'@ 

# Parse JSON 
$settingsObject = $original |ConvertFrom-Json

# Modify resulting object
$settingsObject.DocumentConfiguration.MockDocumentTypes = 
  [pscustomobject]@{
    From = @(
      'LoanStatement'
      'BillingStatement'
    )
  }

# Convert back to JSON and write back to file
$settingsObjects |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | Set-Content appsettings.json
```

Comment: Hi Mathias R. Jessen, Do I need to read the file in with get-content? I'm getting an Invalid JSON primitive error when running the script.

Comment: @ShellGames Sorry, I didn't see this comment until now - did you manage to sort out the issue with reading the file?

Comment: Yes. In-elegantly, but yes. In order to get the section working right now. I have separate files. One for dev/qa and another for our higher environments.